# How to resolve first registration user mobile app

Tags: user-interface, google-play, app-store, publish, user-experience

i’m writing because i’ve a very big doubt to get answered... i’ve created an app that require a lot of users for enjoy at 100% because it shows some posts info at globally level, but my question is: the first user that is registered didn’t see anything inside the app because is all empty

How can i resolve this doubt?

Comment: kindly check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your question. There should be some strategy for launching such applications.

**First Launch Strategy :**

- When you are launching such application specially on both the platforms make sure you should schedule the launching
- Most importantly for a specific laugh day you should arrange a small launching event with Friends or Family to which you can invite on the launch event & can provide a demonstration of the application
- Make sure while before or immediately after launching you should have at least 50 users there. So now you need to target from where you should get this users
- If you are running company they should be your staff members or if you have a good friend circle you should request them
- If your application doesn't requires a real users than in that case you can create at least few dummy users whom you can remove later on when you have enough genuine users
- Also try & get some good reviews / ratings for the application
- Use google analytics & try to understand which feature are used more by the user & try focus improving & adding more facility to that feature
- Use Push notification & Local notifications to let your app interact with the user & daily remind them to use the application. That will improve your app indexing.

**Promotional Campaigns :**

- Another most important thing is when you first launch the application there is a default boost provides by the application for 24-48 hours to let your application fly
- So try & utilise that time to get maximum user engagement & make your app maximum visible across the users

**Reason behind the strategy :**

- If you wants to attract or inspire users to get connect with your app they will already first check how many users using this app. How is the ratings of the application. Ratings will always matter.

I hope you & everyone get help from this answer.